# Linked list segfault on insertion/printing

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a linked list with a struct and insert/print functions as follows,

```
typedef struct node{
    int size;
    int day;
    int year;
    char* month;
    char* fileName;
    struct node *next;
}node;

void insert(node ** head, int size, int year, int day, char* month, char* fileName){
    node * newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->size = size;
    newNode->fileName = fileName;
    newNode->day = day;
    newNode->month = month;
    newNode->year = year;
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
    puts("insert called");
    //printf("head is %s\n", newNode->fileName);
}
void print_list(node * head) {
    node * current = head;
    while (current != NULL){
        puts("got here");
        printf("head %s\n", current->fileName);
        current = current->next;
        printf("next filename %s\n", current->fileName);
    }
}
```

When I call the insert function, It prints the "insert called" message as expected for the number of times I have called that function. So my guess is that the insert function is not the problem.

My problem is that I get a Segfault after the print function prints the first few nodes in the list (It works fine for the first two nodes!)

Here is the rest of the code where the insert function is called,
I don't think it is a problem in her but I could be mistaken :

All of the calls to the linked list functions are toward the bottom

```
void p5aFlag(char* pathName){
    DIR* d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    struct stat s;
    struct tm *tp;
    char* fileName;
    char temp2[strlen(pathName)];
    char * month;
    time_t t;
    d = opendir(pathName);
    int year;
    int day;
    int size;
    node *head = NULL;
    int flag = 0;

    if(d){   //While there are more files in the directory, keep reading them off
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
            fileName = dir->d_name; //store the name of the directory that was just read in fileName
            strcpy(temp2,pathName); // copy the directory name into temp2

            if(strcmp(fileName, ".") != 0 && strcmp(fileName, "..") != 0){ // get file info if the file isn't "." or ".."
                strncat(temp2,"/",2); // prepare the path to lead to another file
                strncat(temp2, fileName, 15); // append the fileName to the path, now we can open this file
                if(stat(temp2, &s) == -1 ){ // if we cannot get information for this file, print error message and exit
                    fprintf(stderr, "couldnt get file info for %s\n", fileName);
                }
                t = s.st_mtime; //store the time that the file was last modified in t
                tp = localtime(&t); // convert to local time
                switch(tp->tm_mon){  // switch to change months from [0-11] to [Jan-Dec]
                    case 0:
                    month = "Jan";
                    break;
                    case 1:
                    month = "Feb";
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    month = "Mar";
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    month = "Apr";
                    break;
                    case 4:
                    month = "May";
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    month = "Jun";
                    break;
                    case 6:
                    month = "Jul";
                    break;
                    case 7:
                    month = "Aug";
                    break;
                    case 8:
                    month = "Sep";
                    break;
                    case 9:
                    month = "Oct";
                    break;
                    case 10:
                    month = "Nov";
                    break;
                    case 11:
                    month = "Dec";
                    break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }
                flag = 1;
            }
            if(flag == 1){
                year = 1900 + tp->tm_year;
                size = s.st_size;
                day = tp->tm_mday;
                insert(&head, size, year, day, month, fileName);
                flag = 0;
            }

            temp2[0]= '\0';
            flag = 0;
        }
        //search(head, ".emacs");
        print_list(head);
        closedir(d); // close the directory
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a segfault when printing the last element because you set current to current->next but don't check if it is `NULL` before printing the next filename:

```
void print_list(node * head) {
    node * current = head;
    while (current != NULL){
        puts("got here");
        printf("head %s\n", current->fileName);
        current = current->next;
        if(current != NULL)   /// add this check
            printf("next filename %s\n", current->fileName);
    }
}
```

You also have a pointless allocation and a memory leak here:

```
node *head = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(node));
head = NULL;
```

You allocate a node but then lose any reference to it by setting head to `NULL`. You can just initialize to `NULL` like this:

```
node *head = NULL;
```

Comment: And the general (don't cast malloc) note: `node *head = malloc (sizeof *head);` is sufficient. (notwithstanding the issue of setting it to `NULL`) @samgak, this isn't directed at you, just a general for those reading. Good answer.

Comment: Thank you for the input, however I have made the changes and now I am getting a Bus error after just the head is printed.

Comment: That wouldn't be caused just by checking for a NULL pointer, it's a separate issue in your code. One thing that you should do is make a copy of the filename string to store in your node instead of using the pointer returned from readdir, which points to a string that get overwritten each time readdir is called.

Comment: @SamWylock - `SIGBUS` generally mean you are trying to access address that is illegal. Is the last `node`'s member `next` initialized to `NULL`? If not, then this will be your culprit.